# Cant change background size because of position absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First of all the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/of6eznLx/)

I'm trying to make the `div` (or the element inside the `div`) background to take the image width and set the background width to it. Because I'm using `jQuery` position I must use the `position: absolute` property which for some reason disables the `background-size` in css and `backgroundSize` in `jQuery`. It can only work with those properties when I delete the position property which disable the `jQuery` position. I tried `margin`/`padding` it didn't work either.

HTML(Wont let me add a picture so couldn't add it)

**JS/jQuery**

```
$('#ShortText').css({
  left: screen.width * .4,
    top: screen.height * .4,
})
```

**CSS**

```
#ShortText{
position:absolute;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255,.6);
background-size:100%;
}
```

My final goal is one of those slideshow images with text on them which when you hover over the text more text shows and I need the background because I don't want to set different color to every text on every picture

EDIT:
Add code & fixed jsfiddle
&more info

Comment: Post a complete code example *in your question* please.

Comment: try position:relative

Comment: Could you elaborate more about what the problem is and what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Added more info about my final goal and plan with it if its not enough I'll try to add more

Answer (score 0):

Your position is absolute, this is not allowing things to change. Changing 'absolute' to 'relative' should fix this. It worked for me in your jsFiddle just by changing that property.